# Check if at least 3 cells in a row have a certain background

Tags: google-apps-script

1) I will have at least 4 columns where cells will have different backgrounds
2) I have to check if at least 3 of cells in a row have per say RED background
3) If it is so - output smth in a cell on that row, per say "WARNING"

I'm no js guy, the only thing I got is:

```
function check() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Canvas');
  if (sheet.getRange("E5").getBackground() == '#ff0e13' && sheet.getRange("F5").getBackground() == '#ff0e13' && sheet.getRange("D5").getBackground() == '#ff0e13') {
    return sheet.getRange('M5').setValue('Warning');
  }
}
```

This on check only certain cells in a certain row. How can I edit that to work with an array ("to drag it on all rows")?

Comment: you can use getactiverange to work within a selection https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()

Comment: Do you want the script to search the whole sheet for every occurrence of the 3 cells combination and update accordingly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to read the background colors in an array and iterate this array row by row counting every occurrence of the red color (or any other color, just adapt in the condition).
Then update the sheet Values in another array and finally write back both arrays to the sheet.

Read comments in code, I added the option to colorize the 'warning' cell but you can remove that if you don't need it.

```
function checkBGColors() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Canvas');
  var maxWidthRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getMaxColumns());// get the whole filled part of the sheet + every possible column
  var BGColors = maxWidthRange.getBackgrounds();
  var Values = maxWidthRange.getValues();
  for(var n=0;n<BGColors.length;n++){
    var count = 0;
    for(var BG in BGColors[n]){
      Logger.log(BGColors[n][BG]);
      if(BGColors[n][BG] == '#ff0000'){
        count++ ; // if BG color is red then increment counter
      }
    }
  Logger.log('Count = '+count);
    if(count >= 3){
      Values[n][12] = 'Warning' ;// column M is index 12, adapt if needed
      BGColors[n][12] = 'Orange';// eventually colorize the warning cell
    }
  }
  maxWidthRange.setValues(Values);// update values
  maxWidthRange.setBackgrounds(BGColors);//update colors
}
```